# Programmatically creating UINavigationController in iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iOS. And I want to use navigation controller in my application but I have no any idea how to do it. So can any one guide me step by step for creating navigation in my application.

Comment: [Navigation controller Programetically](http://www.idev101.com/learn/navigation_controllers.html) [Navigation controller in storyboard](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/)

Comment: have u used in stroyborad or xib in your xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ImageViewController2 *dealVC = (ImageViewController2 *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImageViewController2"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dealVC animated:YES];
```

where ImageViewController2 is a class name

Answer (score 15):

In **appDelegate.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;
```

and set the delegate `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and synthesise object in `appDelegate.m`
now,

**appDelegate.m**

you can set navigation controller in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    frstVwCntlr = [[firstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.frstVwCntlr];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In the above code , your firstViewController is set to `UINavigationController` and `UINavigationController` added to `UIWindow` like

`self.window.rootViewController = self.navController`

Hope this may help you

Comment: If it is valuable for you than Please like the answer @user3418619

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create everything programmatically you have to do it in AppDelegate.

But if you don't want to do it programmatically, then just select the ViewController in Storyboard then select menu options:

`Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller`

Answer (score 1):

You can creat UINavigationController in Appdelegate and set your first viewcontroller on it.

Answer (score 1):

So for creating a UINavigationController programatically without using storyboards, go to your  app delegate and do the following. Create two properties, window and viewController

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    self.viewController = [[YourFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you should write in app delegate.

```
UIViewController *vc=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"vc1" bundle:nil];
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[vc setView:view];

self.navme=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navme;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.0, using filter:

```
let desiredController = self.navigationController!.viewControllers.filter { $0 is YourController }.first!
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(desiredController, animated: true)
```