# Creating a navigation controller using single view application

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to create a single view application using navigation controller.

How can I do that or post a link for the same?

Comment: Why do you want a navigation controller in a single view application?

Comment: Thats what my professor wanted me to do

Comment: your answer shoes how to do it using storyboard, but I wanted to do it without storeyboard

Comment: I have a new problem, I would tag you over there. It would be very kind of you if you could answer that

Comment: I'll take a look. I thought that I put the code under the way to do it in the storyboard. Scroll to the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you would want a navigation controller in a single view application, but here is how you do it.

If you are using the Storyboard select the view controller icon on your inital `ViewController`, then:

Go to Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller

[image]

And that will add your navigation controller.

[image]

If you want to do it programmatically, then you will want to implement this code in the `AppDelegate`'s method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
UIViewController *bbp=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"UIViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bbp];
// [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
  [passcodeNavigationController release];
```

If you are ever interested in Swift I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793331/creating-a-navigationcontroller-programatically-swift), and the accepted answer seemed pretty good:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var nav1 = UINavigationController()
var mainView = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) //ViewController = Name of your controller
nav1.viewControllers = [mainView]
self.window!.rootViewController = nav1
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And here is the converted code (might be buggy) from the Objective-C:

```
var bbp: UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "UIViewController", bundle: nil)
var passcodeNavigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: bbp)
// [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
navigationController.pushViewController(passcodeNavigationController, animated: true)
passcodeNavigationController
```