# How to Navigate all views of application using Navigation Controller in ios using Swift (I am using Xib not Storyboard)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller

(I searched but could not find any working solution)

I have created 5 Xib's which are representing different screens of my application. Now I want to add navigation in my application so that user can go back and forth. I also want to pass data between view controllers. I have done this before, usinig Storyboard that was simple. But i do not have any idea how to do it with Xib.

I am using xcode 7.3 and swift 2.0

Proper guidelines will be highly appreciated thanks.

Comment: reason for downvote ?

Comment: have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It may help you.

AppDelegate.swift

```
var window: UIWindow?
var nav:UINavigationController!

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
{
    let FirstVC = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil) as HomeViewController
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FirstVC)
    nav.navigationBarHidden = true
    self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Then when you want to push the other view controller , simple use following code to move to another view controller.

```
@IBAction func pushHomeVC(sender: UIButton)
{
     let homeVC = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil) as HomeViewController
     // If you want to data pass in Second Screen.
     homeVC.strData = "Pass data that you want"
     let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
     appDelegate.nav.pushViewController(homeVC, animated: true) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working. Now I have two small questions 1) Which method is called in FirstViewController when user perform back navigation from SeconsViewController.    2) How can I share data between ViewControllers using this method ?

Comment: have you use custom navigation bar or default?

Comment: I Have a HomeScreenViewController.xib which I am suing in appDelegate as you said

Comment: It is working, Navgiation is okay Now I want to share Data Between my ViewControllers

Comment: @UmairAfzal simple make an object in your second view controller in which you want to data pass. see my updated answer.

Comment: @UmairAfzal If you have helpful my answer then please approve it. So,Other users that face same issues will find it as helpful and needful.

Comment: I was about to do that.

Comment: @UmairAfzal Thanks for that.