# Can't push from programmatically created UINavigationController

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller

In a Swift 3 project using Xcode 8.3 and iOS 10.3, I get a navigation controller to push. The app runs with a navigation controller until I try to use it to push. All works until the last line which cause an app crash, `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I don't want to use the storyboard, the point of this question is how to accomplish this task without the storyboard.

App Delegate code

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController())

}
```

View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let navController = navigationController

        let myProfileViewController = MyProfileViewController()

        navController!.pushViewController(myProfileViewController, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
let navController = navigationController
let myProfileViewController = MyProfileViewController()

navController!.pushViewController(myProfileViewController, animated: true)
```

from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`.

In `viewDidLoad` there is no parent navigation controller set up and you should not start animations from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add navigation controller in storyboard,
in Storyboard click on MainViewController & from editor menu add navigation controller & push via navigation controller as below code.

```
  let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyProfileViewController") as! MyProfileViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Make sure storyboard identifier is correct. & remove navigation controller code form AppDelegate class.

Comment: I don't want to use the storyboard. I do know how to do this in the storyboard, I want to know how to do this programmatically but thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

first give name to your navigation controller like this
[image]

then in your code initialise it like this 
`let nav = (UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourNavigation") as! UINavigationController);
nav.pushFrontViewController(MainViewController(), animated: true);
window?.rootViewController = nav`

Comment: My nav controller was created programmatically, there is nothing in the storyboard.

Comment: That's all of it above. It should be sufficient to reproduce the error.

Comment: well then then the problem you are facing is  that you have declared your MainViewController but UINavigationController is not been declared or initialised, i am sorry but my expertise is limited

Comment: Then how do I do that? Please write up your reply as an answer.

Comment: there is one solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793331/creating-a-navigationcontroller-programatically-swift see if it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141739/discussion-between-adam-and-markhorrocks).