# navigation controller pushViewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm creating an application that has 2 main view controllers at the moment. The app loads into the initial viewController, and clicking a button inside should bring up the second viewController. Here's what I have:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController1.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController1 *mainViewCtr;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    _mainViewCtr = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"mainViewCtr" bundle:nil];
    _navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_mainViewCtr];
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    _window.rootViewController = _navigationController;
    _navigationController.delegate = self;
    _navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [_window addSubview:_navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

and my button method inside `viewcontroller1`:

```
- (IBAction)SessionNickNameSubmit:(id)sender {
    ViewController2 *secondViewCtrl = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewCtrl" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewCtrl animated:YES];
}
```

but when I click the button the view doesn't change. I tried debugging and the code is hit, but nothing happens.

am I missing a setting somewhere?

***UPDATE***

I've updated all viewController variable names:

instead of `ViewController1/2` I'm using `mainViewCtrl` and `secondViewCtrl`

but still no use :(

Comment: @Sujania I commented it out and its still not working

Comment: What is your _joinViewController? And yes you need _navigationController.delegate = self.

Comment: i think your mistake is here _window.rootViewController = _joinViewController;// chage this statement to  _window.rootViewController = _navigationController. @Abdul Ahmad

Comment: _window.rootViewController = _navigationController;

Comment: I see, I'll try and get back to you guys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981610/programatically-creating-uinavigationcontroller-in-ios refer this link @AbdulAhmad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at almost every tutorial and every stack overflow answer, I finally found a solution that worked. I had to make an instance of the storyboard in the app delegate and use that to create my first view controller instance.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.joinViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:joinViewController];
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    _window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [_window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I think the problem was that when I was creating an instance of `ViewController`, it was creating a new instance and binding the `navigation controller` to it (independent of the view controller that was showing up in the simulator). So when I was using the push method it wasn't recognizing `self.NavigationController` (that's why `NSLog(self.NavigationController == nil)` was logging `1`

Answer (score 5):

You made a typo:

it's

```
_window.rootViewController = _navigationController;
```

not

```
_window.rootViewController = _joinViewController;
```

And NeverHopeless's suggestion is also spot on. It's probably the typo AND the fact that you add your second `viewcontroller` as `ViewController2` and not using a proper variable name.

Another suggestion is making a storyboard (if you are not using one) and adding a segue for the transition. Simply assign the segue processing to the button. Like this:

```
-(IBAction)SessionNicknameSubmit:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self ];
}
```

[Here](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/) is a nice description of how it works and how to use it plus some useful pointers!

Comment: thanks for the help, but its not working, I've updated my variable names (see my updated question)

Comment: Update the code in your question with the new corrections made plz. We can have a better picture then of what is wrong.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad you write this statement _window.rootViewController = _navigationController;. you understand or not?

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya yea I think so.

Comment: _navigationController.delegate = self; remove this line in your code @AbdulAhmad

Comment: no my bad, they're not in my code, just on here, I'll fix them

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya ok I removed it but still no luck

Comment: by the way I added an `NSLog(@"%i", self.navigationController == nil);` in my button click method and its logging `1` so does that mean it can't recognize navigationController?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad I made an edit to my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: I just did this and it works. But I'd still like to figure out how to do it programmatically with 2 separate .XIB files

Comment: @AbdulAhmad Yes of course. That's the purpose of the storyboard. To make the story of your application. You specify there what are the viewcontrollers of your navigationcontroller and how will they transition from one another.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad I added a link for you in the answer to check how storyboards function

Answer (score 1):

Obj-C is a case sensitive language, class name and instance name should not be the same like `ViewController2`. Try like this:

```
- (IBAction)SessionNickNameSubmit:(id)sender {
    ViewController2 *viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have set the window's rootViewController to ViewController1.

You need to set you navigation controller to the window's rootViewController.

So that when you try to access the self.navigationController on the press of the button, it will access the navigation controller in which the self resides i.e. your window's rootViewController now.

Then it will push the next view controller properly.

Comment: Do one thing...
when you set the window's root view controller as the navigation controller, check the memory address for that object.
And when you are trying to push the second view controller, at that time also check for the memory address for self.navigationController.

Are both pointing to the same address?